# Phonegap password prompt

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i want to make a password prompt in phonegap.
any plugins or html/js snippet

i have tried

```
function onPrompt(results) {
    alert("You selected button number " + results.buttonIndex + " and entered " + results.input1);
}

// Show a custom prompt dialog
//
function showPrompt() {
    navigator.notification.prompt(
        'Please enter your name',  // message
        onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
        'Registration',            // title
        ['Ok','Exit']              // buttonLabels
    );
}
```

but it doesnt have any option for password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the native code to display password promt.
As I never need a "normal prompt", I have changed the code in the phonegap plugins for iOS and android but I am sure there is a better way to do it.

for iOS in Plugins/CDVNotification.m

```
   - (void)showDialogWithMessage:(NSString*)message title:(NSString*)title buttons:(NSArray*)buttons defaultText:(NSString*)defaultText callbackId:(NSString*)callbackId dialogType:(NSString*)dialogType
{

CDVAlertView* alertView = [[CDVAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:title
              message:message
             delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:nil
    otherButtonTitles:nil];

alertView.callback

Id = callbackId;

    int count = [buttons count];

    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
        [alertView addButtonWithTitle:[buttons objectAtIndex:n]];
    }

    if ([dialogType isEqualToString:DIALOG_TYPE_PROMPT]) {
        alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput; /*this is what you need*/
        UITextField* textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        textField.text = defaultText;
    }

    [alertView show];
}
```

and for android in src/org/apache/cordova/dialogs/notification.java

```
public synchronized void prompt(final String message, final String title, final JSONArray buttonLabels, final String defaultText, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        final CordovaInterface cordova = this.cordova;
        final EditText promptInput =  new EditText(cordova.getActivity());
        promptInput.setHint(defaultText);
        promptInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
...
```

Comment: I've made this changes but it's not working for me do you do it in the plugins folder root level or in the platforms/ios/APP_NAME/Plugins?

Comment: It depends, for testing I suggest in your app/plugin. Then copy the code of your plugin into your root to "save" your changes for further phonegap build.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one line in

*App Name\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\dialogs\Notification.java*

```
promptInput.setInputType(0x00000081);
```