# How to hide password in phonegap prompt

Tags: android, cordova, passwords, hide, prompt

I'm building a phonegap app and I want to use prompt. Here is my code from index.js

```
navigator.notification.prompt(
                    'Please enter your password',  // message
                    startSmsPrompt,                // callback
                    'Login',                       // title
                    ['Ok','Cancel'],               // buttonName
                    'Password'                     // hint
                );
```

The problem is when the prompt opens and I enter the password, its in clear text (meaning, the characters aren't replaced with * or bullets). I want to hide the password. I also tried changing the code in

*plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/src/android/Notification.java*

I changed the promptInput to

```
promptInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

And

```
promptInput.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

But these two changes, made no difference to my prompt dialog. I want to hide the password, any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap password prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344509/phonegap-password-prompt)

Comment: Maybe use a HTML dialog instead of the notificaion plugin?

Comment: @AlonAmir Yes this question is a duplicate but that's because the solution there didn't solve my issue.

Comment: @QuickFix Yeah, I think now I'll just have to use some other custom plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on this thread.

[Set inputType for an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Turns out you just need to add one line in

*App Name\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\dialogs\Notification.java*

```
promptInput.setInputType(0x00000081);
```